# Binary Search Simulator

Tags: java, loops, iteration, indexoutofboundsexception, binary-search

Why is my program not working? This is my code...

```
public class Binary {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> targets = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    
    for (int x = 0; x < 500; x++) {
        int rand = rand();
        targets.add(rand);
    }
    
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    
    for (int x = 0; x < 5000; x++) {
        numbers.add(x);
    }
    
    ArrayList<Integer> comparisons = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    
    for (Integer x : targets) {
        comparisons.add(binary(numbers, x));
    }
    
    int total = 0;
    for (int z = 0; z < 500; z++) {
        total += comparisons.get(z);
    }
    
    int max = comparisons.get(0);
    for (int z = 1; z < 500; z++) {
        if (comparisons.get(z) >= max) {
            max = comparisons.get(z); 
        }
    }
    
    int min = comparisons.get(0);
    for (int z = 1; z < 500; z++) {
        if (comparisons.get(z) <= max) {
            min = comparisons.get(z); 
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println("The average number of comparisons was...     " + total / 500);
    System.out.println("The minimum number of comparisons was...     " + min);
    System.out.println("The maximum number of comparisons was...     " + max);
}

public static int rand() {
    
    int x = (int) (Math.random() * 5000); 
    return x;
}

public static int binary(List<Integer> arr, int target) {
    if (arr.get(arr.size() - 1) == target) {
        return 1; 
    }
    else if (arr.get(arr.size() - 1) < target) {
        return 1 + binary(arr.subList(arr.size() / 2 + 1, arr.size()), target);
    }
    else {
        return 1 + binary(arr.subList(0, arr.size() / 2 + 1), target);
    }
}
```

}

Here is the error message...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: -1, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:1227)
at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.get(ArrayList.java:1044)
at marcoB.Binary.binary(Binary.java:58)
at marcoB.Binary.binary(Binary.java:62)
at marcoB.Binary.binary(Binary.java:62)
at marcoB.Binary.binary(Binary.java:62)
at marcoB.Binary.binary(Binary.java:62)
at marcoB.Binary.binary(Binary.java:62)
at marcoB.Binary.binary(Binary.java:62)
at marcoB.Binary.binary(Binary.java:62)
at marcoB.Binary.binary(Binary.java:62)
at marcoB.Binary.binary(Binary.java:62)
at marcoB.Binary.binary(Binary.java:62)
at marcoB.Binary.binary(Binary.java:62)
at marcoB.Binary.binary(Binary.java:65)
at marcoB.Binary.main(Binary.java:24)
```

It seems to be indicating that there is a problem on line 24: comparisons.add(binary(numbers, x));

I don't understand why this specifically is causing an issue. There are multiple other lines that are similar, yet eclipse is not signaling an error for any of those lines. If anyone has any suggestions or can catch the error I have made please let me know.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Your binary method do not have the check to stop whether the input array is empty - for instance, `arr.subList(arr.size() / 2 + 1, arr.size())` would be empty array if the size of arr is 1. Adding a simple check like this at the beginning of binary method should solve your problem

`if (arr.size() == 0) return 1;`

Comment: Thank you so so so much.